# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme')

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I 'm trying to develop and android app and I'm stuck with this error for days. I know there are similar questions byt reading them unfortunately didn't help me.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kostas.android.waveradio"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.kostas.android.waveradio.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
  </manifest>
```

My styles.xml file

```
<resources>

  <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

  </style>

     <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base"    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay"   parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

  </resources>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info. Please accept if it solved your answer or if it helped you to finding it and upvote (if you'd like). This will give you reputation and also donate rep to me.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you much understand how Android styles work. [Here's a detailed tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any style in your `styles.xml` with the name "`AppTheme`".

E.G:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> <!-- This means your Activity will be using the Light theme with no ActionBar -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item> <!-- This is the primary color of your app, it is used for the ActionBar/Toolbar for example. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item> <!-- Color of Status bar on API 21+ -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item> <--This is the accent color, used for FloatingActionBar and other things like the EditText divider -->
</style>
```

Now, you're probably wondering "What are `@color/primary`" (*otherwise you don't know what the error you're currently getting is*).

Go to your `colors.xml` (`res>values>colors.xml`) and define `primary`, `primary_dark`, and `accent` with the colors that you want. (I suggest [this site](https://www.materialpalette.com/) to do it for you as it picks good material colors):

```
<color name="primary"><!-- Your color --></color>
<color name="primary_dark"><!-- Your color --></color>
<color name="acent"><!-- Your color --></color>
```

Remember to replace `<!-- Your color -->` with your desired colors (such as `#3367d6`)

Here's an image explaining what each attribute does.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I used the code you gave me in my styles.xml, but now I have the error: "Error:(267, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/accent'). "

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the link! now I'm getting this error: "Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Material Theme.Base'."

Comment: @KostasSt what line?